# libdeflate0 is kept back - dependency conflict

Tags: apt, dependencies

I updated my Ubuntu 20.04.4 to be able to upgrade it to 22.04.1, but I am experiencing problems with `libdeflate0`. As already mentioned in the title, there is a dependency conflict:

```
sudo apt list --upgradable -a
Listing... Done
libdeflate0/focal 1.12-1~20.04.sav0 amd64 [upgradable from: 1.8-1ubuntu1~20.04.sav0]
libdeflate0/now 1.8-1ubuntu1~20.04.sav0 amd64 [installed,upgradable to: 1.12-1~20.04.sav0]
libdeflate0/focal 1.5-3 amd64
```

none of the above is a suitable option, because of unmet dependencies. Thus, I tried:

```
sudo aptitude remove libdeflate0
The following packages will be REMOVED:  
  libdeflate0 
0 packages upgraded, 0 newly installed, 1 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
Need to get 0 B of archives. After unpacking 129 kB will be freed.
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 libtiff5 : Depends: libdeflate0 (>= 1.0) but it is not going to be installed
The following actions will resolve these dependencies:

     Keep the following packages at their current version:
1)     libdeflate0 [1.8-1ubuntu1~20.04.sav0 (now)]
Accept this solution? [Y/n/q/?]
```

with no suitable results. Typing `n`, the other options (more than 15) suggested removing many programs (e.g., wine and wine32), because of the spread of this packages across the dependencies. Then I tried:

```
sudo dpkg -l --force-remove-reinstreq libdeflate0
Desired=Unknown/Install/Remove/Purge/Hold
| Status=Not/Inst/Conf-files/Unpacked/halF-conf/Half-inst/trig-aWait/Trig-pend
|/ Err?=(none)/Reinst-required (Status,Err: uppercase=bad)
||/ Name              Version                 Architecture Description
+++-=================-=======================-============-==============================================================
ri  libdeflate0:amd64 1.8-1ubuntu1~20.04.sav0 amd64        fast, whole-buffer DEFLATE-based compression and decompression
ii  libdeflate0:i386  1.8-1ubuntu1~20.04.sav0 i386         fast, whole-buffer DEFLATE-based compression and decompression
```

without success. Do you have any suggestion on how to proceed?

EDIT: in case I chose other solutions from `aptitude`, the following list of programs would be REMOVED:

```
The following packages will be REMOVED:
  fonts-wine{u} glib-networking:i386{u} gstreamer1.0-plugins-base:i386{u} gstreamer1.0-plugins-good:i386{a} 
  gstreamer1.0-x:i386{u} i965-va-driver:i386{u} intel-media-va-driver:i386{u} libaa1:i386{u} libaom0:i386{u} 
  libapparmor1:i386{u} libaribb24-0:i386{u} libasn1-8-heimdal:i386{u} libasound2:i386{u} libasound2-plugins:i386{u} 
  libasyncns0:i386{u} libavahi-client3:i386{u} libavahi-common-data:i386{u} libavahi-common3:i386{u} 
  libavc1394-0:i386{u} libavcodec-extra58:i386{a} libavutil56:i386{u} libbrotli1:i386{u} libcaca0:i386{u} 
  libcairo-gobject2:i386{u} libcairo2:i386{u} libcap2:i386{u} libcapi20-3:i386{u} libcdparanoia0:i386{u} 
  libcodec2-0.9:i386{u} libcups2:i386{u} libcurl3-gnutls:i386{u} libdatrie1:i386{u} libdbus-1-3:i386{u} 
  libdeflate0:i386{a} libdv4:i386{u} libexif12:i386{u} libfaudio0:i386{a} libflac8:i386{u} libfontconfig1:i386{u} 
  libfreetype6:i386{u} libfribidi0:i386{u} libgd3:i386{a} libgdbm-compat4:i386{u} libgdbm6:i386{u} 
  libgdk-pixbuf2.0-0:i386{a} libglib2.0-0:i386{u} libglu1-mesa:i386{u} libgmp10:i386{u} libgnutls30:i386{u} 
  libgomp1:i386{u} libgphoto2-6:i386{a} libgphoto2-port12:i386{u} libgraphite2-3:i386{u} libgsm1:i386{u} 
  libgssapi-krb5-2:i386{u} libgssapi3-heimdal:i386{u} libgstreamer-plugins-base1.0-0:i386{u} 
  libgstreamer-plugins-good1.0-0:i386{u} libgstreamer1.0-0:i386{u} libgudev-1.0-0:i386{u} libharfbuzz0b:i386{u} 
  libhcrypto4-heimdal:i386{u} libheimbase1-heimdal:i386{u} libheimntlm0-heimdal:i386{u} libhogweed5:i386{u} 
  libhx509-5-heimdal:i386{u} libicu66:i386{u} libiec61883-0:i386{u} libieee1284-3:i386{u} libigdgmm11:i386{u} 
  libjack-jackd2-0:i386{u} libjbig0:i386{u} libjpeg-turbo8:i386{u} libjpeg8:i386{u} libk5crypto3:i386{u} 
  libkeyutils1:i386{u} libkrb5-26-heimdal:i386{u} libkrb5-3:i386{u} libkrb5support0:i386{u} liblcms2-2:i386{u} 
  libldap-2.4-2:i386{u} libltdl7:i386{u} libmp3lame0:i386{u} libmpg123-0:i386{u} libmysqlclient21:i386{u} 
  libnettle7:i386{u} libnghttp2-14:i386{u} libnuma1:i386{u} libodbc1:i386{u} libogg0:i386{u} libopenal1:i386{u} 
  libopencore-amrnb0:i386{u} libopencore-amrwb0:i386{u} libopenjp2-7:i386{u} libopus0:i386{u} liborc-0.4-0:i386{u} 
  libosmesa6:i386{u} libp11-kit0:i386{u} libpango-1.0-0:i386{u} libpangocairo-1.0-0:i386{u} libpangoft2-1.0-0:i386{u} 
  libpcap0.8:i386{u} libpci3:i386{u} libperl5.30:i386{u} libpixman-1-0:i386{u} libpng16-16:i386{u} libproxy1v5:i386{u} 
  libpsl5:i386{u} libpulse0:i386{u} libraw1394-11:i386{u} libroken18-heimdal:i386{u} librsvg2-2:i386{a} 
  librsvg2-common:i386{a} librtmp1:i386{u} libsamplerate0:i386{u} libsane:i386{a} libsasl2-2:i386{u} 
  libsasl2-modules:i386{u} libsasl2-modules-db:i386{u} libsdl2-2.0-0:i386{u} libshine3:i386{u} libshout3:i386{u} 
  libslang2:i386{u} libsnappy1v5:i386{u} libsndfile1:i386{u} libsndio7.0:i386{u} libsnmp35:i386{u} libsoup2.4-1:i386{u} 
  libsoxr0:i386{u} libspeex1:i386{u} libsqlite3-0:i386{u} libssh-4:i386{u} libssl1.1:i386{u} libstb0:i386{u} 
  libswresample3:i386{u} libtag1v5:i386{u} libtag1v5-vanilla:i386{u} libtasn1-6:i386{u} libthai0:i386{u} 
  libtheora0:i386{u} libtiff5:i386{a} libtwolame0:i386{u} libusb-1.0-0:i386{u} libv4l-0:i386{u} libv4lconvert0:i386{u} 
  libva-drm2:i386{u} libva-x11-2:i386{u} libva2:i386{u} libvdpau1:i386{u} libvisual-0.4-0:i386{u} libvkd3d1:i386{u} 
  libvo-amrwbenc0:i386{u} libvorbis0a:i386{u} libvorbisenc2:i386{u} libvpx6:i386{u} libwavpack1:i386{u} 
  libwayland-cursor0:i386{u} libwayland-egl1:i386{u} libwebp6:i386{u} libwebp7:i386{u} libwebpmux3:i386{u} 
  libwind0-heimdal:i386{u} libwine:i386{a} libwrap0:i386{u} libx264-155:i386{u} libx265-179:i386{u} 
  libxcb-render0:i386{u} libxcomposite1:i386{u} libxcursor1:i386{u} libxdamage1:i386{u} libxi6:i386{u} 
  libxinerama1:i386{u} libxkbcommon0:i386{u} libxml2:i386{u} libxpm4:i386{u} libxrandr2:i386{u} libxrender1:i386{u} 
  libxslt1.1:i386{u} libxss1:i386{u} libxv1:i386{u} libxvidcore4:i386{u} libzvbi0:i386{u} mesa-va-drivers:i386{u} 
  mesa-vdpau-drivers:i386{u} ocl-icd-libopencl1:i386{u} va-driver-all:i386{u} vdpau-driver-all:i386{u} wine{a} 
  wine32:i386{a} 
The following packages will be upgraded:
  libdeflate0 
1 packages upgraded, 0 newly installed, 189 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
Need to get 77,1 kB of archives. After unpacking 579 MB will be freed.
```

to me, it sounds like a lot to be on the safe side (although I have Timeshift).

EDIT2: here the output of `apt policy` as requested:

```
apt policy libdeflate0
libdeflate0:
  Installed: 1.8-1ubuntu1~20.04.sav0
  Candidate: 1.12-1~20.04.sav0
  Version table:
     1.12-1~20.04.sav0 500
        500 http://ppa.launchpad.net/savoury1/digikam/ubuntu focal/main amd64 Packages
 *** 1.8-1ubuntu1~20.04.sav0 100
        100 /var/lib/dpkg/status
     1.5-3 500
        500 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal/universe amd64 Packages
```

Comment: Remove wine and wine32 do the upgrade and reinstall.

Comment: the list of the libs and programs to be removed is massive, I don't think the problem lies on wine.

Comment: libdeflate0 in 20.04 is version 1.5-3 as shipped by Ubuntu. You seem to have 1.8-1ubuntu1~20.04.sav0. Ubuntu never shipped this, so presumably it is installed by some third party repository that is causing conflicts. You might want to contact that third party for support, or at least report to them that their instructions are breaking users' systems.

Comment: Please add the output of `apt policy libdeflate0` to your question. This will quickly show the origin of the problematic package.

Comment: I'd ppa-purge that digikam ppa. You'll need to get rid of it to upgrade anyway. Oddly, your `libdeflate0` is orphaned, so unclear where it came from. It appears there are serious issues with packages on your system.

Comment: I purged digikam (it was empty) and removed other old ppa as well. It could definitely be that there are problems with some packages, this is my very first Linux distro. I was considering to migrate to a fresh installation of 22.04.1, without trying to fix whatever mess I could have done.

Comment: @OrganicMarble removing the unused ppa and performing `sudo aptitude update` and `upgrade` solved the issue!

Comment: Good news! `apt policy` is a powerful tool for your toolbox!

Answer (score 0):

Answer `n` to the question. If this removes a lot of packages, then have these removed. Then fully update the system with a `sudo apt dist-upgrade` and proceed with the upgrade to Ubuntu 22.04. Once booted into Ubuntu 22.04, reinstall the packages. All user configuration will have been preserved.